# Unable to call javascript function inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have function `getUrl()` which extracts value from cell of a table and then it constructs a url which is used for sUpdateURL for editing a cell .

but `getUrl()` function is not being called .

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function getUrl(){
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var url=null;
    tbody.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var data = [];

        var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
        while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if (target) {
            var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);

            }
        }
        var comp_name=data[1];
        var comp_desc=data[2];
        url="updateComponent.htm?comp_name="+comp_name+"&comp_desc="+comp_desc+"";
    };
    return url;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#component_table').dataTable().makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: getUrl(),
        "aoColumns": [
                    null,{},{} 
                    ]
    });
});
```

Comment: call without parenthesis  `sUpdateURL: getUrl,`

Comment: I am not sure about the datatable stuff, if it doesn't  support method calling, why dont you call the method and assign the url value to a variable.? then you can use that variable inside the datatable code.

Comment: What makes you think that the function is not being called?

Comment: Don't you have to assign it to a variable to be able to do that? `var getUrl = function getUrl(){`

Comment: @JqueryKing How is that supposed to help?

Comment: Actually, getUrl() will always return null, you probably want to **remove** the click listener and get the URL value once the document has been completely loaded. Also, as JqueryKing pointed out above, call the function without the parenthesis, because you need to reference that function.

Answer (score 3):

Your `getUrl()` function will **always** return `null`. The `url` variable is only set when a "click" event is handled by that event handler it sets up.

Comment: then how can i proceed.onclick of a cell it should update the database based on the queryparam I am passing

Comment: @TapajyotiGiri you'd have to perform the update from the event handler, or something. The code you've got really just doesn't make any sense.